# Laravel: How to Queue mails to send later

Tags: php, laravel, queue, sendmail

Im trying to use the Mail::queue to send and email, but when I call this function it simple sends the mail, and the response is delayed ... I thought that the point of using Mail::queue was to queue ....

I want the response to came instantly, not having to wait for the email to be sent

for eg

```
Mail::queue('emails.template', $data, function($message) {
    $message->to('somemail@gmail.com');
    $message->subject('Notificacion');
});

return Response::json(array('error' => 0, 'message' => 'Ok'));
```

I want to receive the response without waiting for the mail to be sent.
How can I do that???

Comment: The method Mail::later does the same thing, it just waits whatever time I tell it to wait and the response is delayed

Comment: It's practically impossible. You will get response from server your operation executed.

Comment: @GabrielMatusevich may I know whether you get any solutions about this? I also meet the same problems when using laravel5

Answer (score 5):

What queue driver (`app/config/queue.php - 'default' param`) are you using? If you're using `sync`, and haven't set up one of the others, then you're using the synchronous driver, which does exactly what the name says: Runs your queued task as soon as the task is created.

You need to configure an MQ server for Laravel to talk to. You can get a free iron.io account for this, and then you need to configure it, for instance:

```
'iron' => array(
    'driver'  => 'iron',
    'project' => 'iron-io-project-id',
    'token'   => 'iron-io-queue-token',
    'queue'   => 'queue-name',
),
```

Then when you use `Mail::queue()` it will push the instruction to iron.io. You'll then have to have another thread listening on the queue - just run `php artisan queue:listen` and leave it running while messages are pushed to the queue.

Comment: This is really helpful but I'm actually looking for some way to do this locally without depending on another service :P

Comment: what about beanstalkd?? do you have an example config for it?

Comment: Using iron.io really will be the fastest way to get it set up. For beanstalkd, once you install it, you should just be able to use the configured defaults - just change `default` on line 18 to `beanstalkd`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 /**
 * Get all email recipients and include their user details for Mailgun's
 * template tags - %recipient.userToken%
 */
private function getRecipients()
{
    foreach (User::get() as $user)
    {
        $this->recipients[$user->email] = [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'userToken' => $user->user_token,
            'first_name' => $user->first_name,
            'last_name' => $user->last_name,
            'email' => $user->email
        ];
    }
}

private function sendEmail()
{
    $subject = 'Demo Subject';
    /**
     * Data for the Blade template
     */
    $data = [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ];
    // Inline the CSS for the email
    $inliner = new InlineEmail('emails.some-email', $data);
    $content = $inliner->convert();

    // Create Emails table entry for this email. Used for Mailgun webhooks
    $email = Email::create(['user_id' => $this->userId, 'subject' => $subject, 'email_id' => str_random()]);

    // Prepare the email addresses
    $emailAddresses = array_column($this->recipients, 'email');

    $this->mailgun->sendMessage('demo.org', [
        "from" => 'support@demo.org',
        "to" => implode(',', $emailAddresses), // Comma separated list of email addresses
        "subject" => $subject,
        "html" => $content, // Inlined CSS HTML from Blade
        "text" => "Plain text message here",
        "recipient-variables" => json_encode($this->recipients), // Required for batch sending, matches to recipient details
        "v:messageId" => $email->id, // Custom variable used for webhooks
    ]);
}
```